# In QGIS *.nc file changes from "NetCDF" to "HDF5"

Tags: hdf5, netcdf, qgis

I am experiencing a strange behavior in QGIS. In a folder, I have NetCDF file (floodings.nc). If I drag this to QGIS, it comes as expected with correct coordinates. Also the Layer toolbar says "NETCDF:floodings: area_1"

Now, if I copy the same file (floodings.nc) to a new folder and drag it to QGIS, the coordinates are completely wrong and I cannot change those to what I want. Also the Layer toolbar is a bit changed, saying "HDF5:floodings:// area_1".

Why does the NETCDF change to HDF5? Can somebody explain this? Is it possible to load the nc-file as NetCDF (not HDF5)?

Comment: Maybe there is something about the "default folder" for NETCDF driver....

Comment: I also noticed that dragging the same nc-file that was copied to another folder to QGIS, in "Select Raster Layers to Add" pop-up window there are two slashes before the layers name ( //area_1 ). Previously there was not ( area_1 )

Comment: So no-one knows why in QGIS the *.nc-files are from one folder opened as NetCDF and from another folder as HDF5?